# Jquery ScrollTop Manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

What's wrong with my else function?

I try to hide the sign-up-box when scrollTop =0 but wasn't able to make the opacity to work. The width change gets executed while the opacity one doesn't (alert does pop up so scrolltop position is at 0).

Would love to hear some insights from Jquery gurus. Thanks!!

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() !== 0 ) {
            $('.sign-up-box').animate({
                right: '100px',
                opacity: 1
            }); 
    } else {                        
        $('.sign-up-box').css('opacity', '0.6');
        $('.sign-up-box').css('width', '300px');
        alert("scrolltop = 0");
    }
});
```

Here is the html for reference:

```
<div class="list-group sign-up-box">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading pull-right">Sign up to our email list</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the css for reference:

```
.sign-up-box {
    position: fixed;
    right: -250px;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
```

Comment: You are mixing between `class` and `ID`. I guess it should be `$('.sign-up-box')` based on your CSS (notice the `.` instead of `#`) .

Comment: In this function you change the opacity to 0.6 when you reach top of the page, not to 0. So it is still visible. And in the first if, i would recommend using >0, its just not that messy. The code looks great, if the alert pops out each time you reach the top, then it should be the css fault.

Comment: Please dump your HTML code in your question.

Comment: hi @D4V1D, i just uploaded the html. any wrong doing you may notice?

Comment: Not that I can think of. What if you try `$('#sign-up-box').css('border-color', 'red');`. Does that work?

Comment: @D4V1D i added your line in front of the alert and it doesn't work. the alert msg still pops up though

Comment: Right, currently JSFiddling it.

Comment: @IannWu: Check my [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31672242/2788131).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did more research regarding the issue and figured that the reason why my css weren't working is because the .animate is being called continuously as we scroll the page (thus .animate is constantly renewed and running) and as a result the animation overrides the css changes (same as what Jimmy said). I also tried using .stop().animate and that works only if i wait long enough for the old animation to complete. Otherwise, if I scroll quickly down and back to top the overriding would occur and I would see no change to the animation.

Regarding David's solution, there is 1 potential drawback, which is .animate being called more than once. I've made some tweak and come up with the following optimized solution:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Keep track of previous scroll position.
            var previousPosition = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function() {

                // If user is scrolling down.
                if($(window).scrollTop() > 40) {

                    // And user is coming from the top.
                    if(previousPosition <= 40) {

                        //Then animate.
                        $('.sign-up-box').animate({
                            right: '100px',
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 400);

                    }
                } else {

                    // If user is scrolling from the bottom.
                    if(previousPosition > 40) {

                        // Then animate.
                        $('.sign-up-box').stop().animate({
                            right: '-200px',
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 400);
                    }
                }

                // Update previous position.
                previousPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
            });
        });
```

What an interesting exploration regarding .animate in JQuery. Thanks everyone for the help!!!

Comment: You can often do animations using the CSS "transition" property, and it is usually a cleaner solution than jQuery's animate function in my opinion.  Perhaps you wouldn't run into the same issues with CSS transitions... not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the animation is currently running with `.is(':animated')` and have your jQuery like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            if(!$('#sign-up-box').is(':animated')) {
                $('#sign-up-box').animate({
                    right: '100px',
                    opacity: 1
                }, 1500);     
            }
        } else {                       
             $('#sign-up-box').animate({
                 right: '-250px',
                 opacity: 0
             }, 1500);       

        }   

    });

});
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ws0oLkc5/2/)

**Additionnal infos**

You can pass an object to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) jQuery method if you have several properties to set, like so:

```
$(this).css({
    opacity: 0,
    color: '#FF0000'
});
```

For one property, you can use the shorter version: `$(this).css('opacity', '0');`.

Comment: Hi David, I'm a bit confused by if(!$('#sign-up-box').is(':animated')).
So does it mean if scrollTop > 0 and sign-up-box is animated, then we apply the change?
When we load the page or scroll the page down for the first time, isn't scrollTop > 0 but there the box isn't animated yet?

Comment: No, it means `if` scrollTop is greater than `0` **and** the animation is **not** currently running, then do the stuff.

Comment: I see!
So if the box is animated, I can't simply apply new css styles to it? I'm still unsure why my original code doesnt work

Comment: I don't know why but I found out that applying `.css('opacity', 0.6);` doesn't work. Animating this property however works.

Comment: Hey David thanks for the edits. I did more research in the issue and figured that the reason why my css werent working is because the .animate is being called continuously (and constantly running) and thus it overrides the css changes (same as what Jimmy said). I also tried using .animate and that works if i wait long enough for the previous animation to complete. Otherwise if I scroll quickly down and back to top the overriding would occur.

Comment: I also figured a better solution to call the animate so that we won't be calling again and again once the animation is complete as we scroll. Will update in a bit

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is a race condition. Say the user isn't scrolled to the top, and we animate. If the user then scrolls to the top when the animation is running, the .css call will modify the style attribute for just that moment, but the still running animation will immediately keep overwriting the "opacity" attribute. The reason why replacing .css with .animate works is that animations queue up (they don't run until other animations are complete). The correct way to do this is to do this:

```
$('#sign-up-box').stop().css('opacity', '0.6');
```

Comment: Hey Jimmy, thanks for the input. I tried .stop but it doesn't work. Seems like if there aren't enough time between calling .animate and .css it somehow messes up the flow.

.stop().animate works if I wait long enough for the previous animate to complete. If i quickly scroll down and back up the older .animate would mess up the scrollTop one as well.